# tableView cell dotted border not rendering properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Consider me novice in iOS programing. I am trying to show dotted border as the separator as well as a vertical dotted border between the fields, please check the screenshot for detailed view. Till now there is no problem, borders are rendering properly.But at the moment tableView get scrolled up or down, the position of vertical dotted lines are getting changed, please check screenshot. I know this is happening due to the `cell reuse` property. For all the cell dotted line creating method is same so, I am unable to find the `culprit line of code`. I am using `ViewController` and attached an `UITableView` to it, connected the datasource and delegates. Here is the code for dotted line creation.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
KKCustList *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custList" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[KKCustList alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"custList"];
}
/** Creating dotted lines for border **/


CAShapeLayer *shapelayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, cell.frame.size.height)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
shapelayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
shapelayer.strokeColor = [UIColor firstRowColor].CGColor;
shapelayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ], nil];
shapelayer.path = path.CGPath;
[cell.layer addSublayer:shapelayer];

/** creating vertical dotted line **/

CAShapeLayer *shapelayer1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[path1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(cell.soLabel.bounds.origin.x + cell.soLabel.bounds.size.width, cell.soLabel.bounds.origin.y + 10)];
[path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(cell.soLabel.bounds.origin.x + cell.soLabel.bounds.size.width, cell.soLabel.bounds.size.height)];
shapelayer1.strokeStart = 0.0;
shapelayer1.strokeColor = [UIColor firstRowColor].CGColor;
shapelayer1.lineWidth = 1.0;
shapelayer1.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapelayer1.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ], nil];
shapelayer1.path = path1.CGPath;
[cell.layer addSublayer:shapelayer1];
```

[image: Desired]
[image: after scrolling]

**UPDATE**
moved the code to awakeFromNib

```
@implementation KKCustList
@synthesize shapelayer1;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

[super awakeFromNib];

 /** creating vertical dotted line **/

    CAShapeLayer *shapelayer1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [path1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.soLabel.bounds.origin.x + self.soLabel.bounds.size.width, self.soLabel.bounds.origin.y + 10)];
    [path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.soLabel.bounds.origin.x + self.soLabel.bounds.size.width, self.soLabel.bounds.size.height)];
    shapelayer1.strokeStart = 0.0;
    shapelayer1.strokeColor = [UIColor firstRowColor].CGColor;
    shapelayer1.lineWidth = 1.0;
    shapelayer1.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
    shapelayer1.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ], nil];
    shapelayer1.path = path1.CGPath;
    [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:shapelayer1];

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't apply any scale in your iPhone Simulator?

Comment: your lines should be added in the cell when it's created, not re-added every time the cell is used. also, have you considered using a different view so you can position it with auto layout...

Comment: By scale u mean cmd+1, cmd+2 on simulator, If yes then no, I didn't apply any scale. Tested on same size simulator.

Comment: @Wain: I applied autolayout constraints on `SO#` label and on the button. So, where should I write, can you explain a bit programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code has a couple of issues:

1. You keep adding new layers, you never remove old ones, so each time a cell is reused it'll take more memory and the lines could be in the wrong place
2. You never move the sublayers when the cell size changes

So you need a couple of different fixes:

1. Add the lines in your cell in `awakeFromNib`, so they're just added once in the same way that all your other views are
2. Override `layoutSubviews` in your cell and move the layers you've added each time it's called so they don't overlap other views

I'd actually drop the sublayers approach probably and use an image view for the line. If the lines might change quite a lot then I'd likely use a custom view class which has a sublayer (as per your current code) and the resizing / layout logic as described above. The reason for that is so that you can apply auto-layout constraints to the view and it will move in relation to the cell and your other views automatically.

You should also remove

```
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[KKCustList alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"custList"];
}
```

because it will never be used, a cell will always be created for you.

Comment: Thanks Wain, trying to understand and implement your answer.

Comment: Please check the update, now lines are not getting shown on the table view. `KKCustList` is my custom cell. I am using storyboard.

Comment: updated the code as suggesting by you, and its working as expected now. But i didn't get your second point, I used to set constraints in storyboard . Can u please, provide some sample code.

Comment: i'd set them in the storyboard by adding the view in the storyboard and setting the class... otherwise find a library to help with constraint addition on github

Comment: What do you mean by setting the class?

Comment: my answer proposes using a custom view subclass